# Cannot execute open queries with parameter in linked server (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2, linked-server

Hi below is a simple query to fetch value from local database and selects values from a DB2 linked server. I am unable to execute it. I am getting an error.

```
Incorrect syntax near 'AU000'.
```

If I run the query standalone like exec(@VAR) it works but Exec(@TSQL) doesn't. Please help. below is the query I am running.

```
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000) , @VAR char(200)          
      select  @VAR = 'select top 1 ''AU000'' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CPHN#)  from upload.cancelledcontractheader'    
      SELECT  @TSQL = '   
      SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(    
      AS400TS_LNK,    
      ''
      select * from TWGTEST.AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT  where ACTRNO ='''''+@VAR+'''''   
      ''
      )   
      '
      EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Finally I want to achieve this

```
     DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000) , @VAR char(200)         

Create table #siteId (id varchar(100))
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'insert into #siteId (id) select (''AU000'' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CPHN#))  from upload.cancelledcontractheader'
exec (@SQL)

 select  @VAR = 'select ''AU000'' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CPHN#)  from upload.cancelledcontractheader'   
              SELECT  @TSQL = '   
              SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(    
              AS400TS_LNK,    
              ''
              insert into AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT (ACTRNO,    ASEQN,  ACTRAL, ASEQA,  ATYPECOD,   ASKU,   AACDTID,    AACCTVR,    ACDTIDD,    AACCTCD,    ASTATUS,    AAMOUNT,    ACRTUSR,    ACRTDTE,    ACRTTIM,    ACHGUSR,    ACHGDTE,    
    ACHGTIM)
    SELECT ACTRNO,  ASEQN,  ACTRAL, ASEQA,  '9123', ASKU,   AACDTID,    AACCTVR,    ACDTIDD,    AACCTCD,    'C',    AAMOUNT,    ACRTUSR,    ACRTDTE,    ACRTTIM,    'SSCE2',    ACHGDTE,    
    ACHGTIM
    from AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT where ACTRNO in '''''+#siteId+'''''   
              ''
              )   
              '
              EXEC (@TSQL)
drop table #siteId
```

Comment: Any help appreciated

Comment: um, which database is `AUPRDDBF.CONTACCT` on?